# How to make service worker handle push when app in background?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push

I am using firebase to send messages to my site's users using `GuzzleHTTP` from my `laravel` app. From what I understand, there are two ways to handle push, one is using the `notification` message and the other is wrapping the `notification` object inside `data`. `notification` uses FirebaseAPI but this doesn't seem to run in the background. It only works when the user had opened the PWA in the last few minutes. I want to send the user notifications regardless of when they last opened their browser. I understand that I should use the `push` eventListener for this and I did place the code for it, but I always seem to get either the firebase API notification(when the site was opened recently) or no notification at all.

Here's my firebase message handler

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  // Customize notification here
  var recep = JSON.stringify(payload);
  recep = JSON.parse(recep);
  var notification = recep.notification;
  //notification = JSON.stringify(notification);
  message = JSON.parse(notification);
  const notificationTitle = message.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: message.body,
    icon: message.icon,
    badge: '/img/favicon.png',
    click_action: messaging.click_action
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

And here's my service worker message or `push` handler:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
  var body;

  if (e.data) {
    body = e.data.json().notification.body;
  } else {
    body = 'Alert from AppMate.Open the app to view details!';
  }

  var options = {
    body: body,
    icon: 'img/favicon.png',
    badge: 'img/favicon.png',
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: 1
    },
    actions: [
      {action: 'ap-mate', title: 'Visit AppMate!'}
    ]
  };
  e.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Appmate Notification', options)
  );
});
```

And here's the request sent to the endpoint through `GuzzleHTTP`:

```
        $message = [
            'data' => [
               'notification' => [
                 'title' => $title,
                 'body' => $body,
                 'icon' => 'img/favicon.png',
                 'badge' => 'img/favicon.png'
             ],
            ],
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'body' => $body,
                'icon' => 'img/favicon.png',
                'badge' => 'img/favicon.png',
                'click_action' => $action
            ],
            'to' => $reg_id
        ];
        $client = new Client([
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'key='.$access_token,
            ]
        ]);
        $response = $client->post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
            ['body' => json_encode($message)]
        );
        return $response->getBody();
```

Comment: I have the same problem.  Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, I ended up using OneSignal for push. Do post an answer here if you get a solution.